# Android SQLite, Query but find no row, gives me error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I tried using cursor == null, but no avail, and cursor.getCount == 0, and the moveFirst method.. still error, heres my code..

```
  public void getColumns()
        {


            String[] columns = new String[] {"CLASSROOM_ID"};
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query("CLASSROOM_TABLE", columns, "CLASSROOM_AVAILABLE =  0", null,
                    null, null, null);

            if (c.moveToFirst())
                    {
                int[] myid = new int[c.getCount()];
                int i = 0;

                while (!c.isAfterLast()) 
                    {

                    myid[i]=c.getInt(0);
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put("CLASSROOM_AVAILABLE", 1);
                    ourDatabase.update("CLASSROOM_TABLE", cv, "CLASSROOM_ID = "+myid[i], null);



                    i++;
                    c.moveToNext();

                    }
                    }




        }
```

I dont really know what im doing wrong, what should i do to make my application know that the cursor find no rows?

this is the logcat

```
10-29 12:04:23.903: D/AndroidRuntime(22782): Shutting down VM
10-29 12:04:23.903: W/dalvikvm(22782): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at my.skul.Mainmenu.sectwenty(Mainmenu.java:71)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    ... 11 more
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:99)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    at my.skul.MyCreateClassrooms.get(MyCreateClassrooms.java:111)
10-29 12:04:23.923: E/AndroidRuntime(22782):    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your cursor to first position by using [moveToFirst()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29)

> This method will return false if the cursor is empty

(or)

Another way is:

```
 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
     //Your logic
    }
```

Comment: thanks, still getting me errors though, trying to work it around, can you post my code wth your editing?.. it still gives me error if no rows is found... check the edit, i edit it with my understanding of your answer, im newbie

Comment: Your code should be, if(c.moveToFirst()){//your code}, move else code to inside if block. Please read and understand what my answer saying.

Comment: Ok, i edit it again, it does work whati wanted (updating) but still gives me error if no rows found..im really sorry if i can't debug it, im really am a newbie

Comment: I am not seeing any exception stack in question, it seems you forgot to update.

Comment: im sorry, what is exception stack? im not an english speaking person..i thought u mean to update my question...

Comment: Exception  you will see in logcat.

Comment: I suspect your issue is,  myid[i]=c.getInt(0); coukd you remove this?

Comment: i cant remove it because, im fetching the id of each rows that has the completion fulfilled, and then edit those rows' "CLASSROOM_AVAILABLE" from 0 to 1... i deleted it, still gives me the same error

Comment: i test it in my other class, it works fine, maybe because its inside of an Intent Service? Mr. Nambari, is being inside of an IntentService(onHandleIntent) result it to error? is there a fix on that?